# VBA vlookup error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, vlookup

There are about 1200 rows with data after the first part of the script has run. Afterwards I want to run a vlookup for column 6, which has the initials of the person handling the problem,  against a central masterlist to see if the initials are allready exisitng or not.

VBA points to the if condition with an 1004 error telling me that the object of the vlookup function is wrong (my vba is in german, loose translation).

```vb
lastrowNF = Worksheets("Neuerfassung").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For k = 9 To lastrowNF
        
nepro = Worksheets("Neuerfassung").Cells(k, 6).Value
        
If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(nepro, Worksheets("Optionen").Range("D3:D5000"), 1)) Then
```

Did I mess up the syntax? Thanks for your help

Comment: remove the `.WorkSheetFunction` part of the Vlookup.  With it whenever there is an error it will stop the code.  Without it will allow vba to pass the error.

Comment: thx that was what was wrong